# JOOQ dynamic conditions query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jooq

Hi everybody i try to make a method to apply conditions a SelectQuery, but i don't know hot get the fields by name or the table by name, the code example...

the filter condition's object is an array and looks like:

```
[{'field': 'ID', 'condition' : 'in', 'value' : ['f4019bc3-d06b-4673-87e7-75bab23ac85a','c13beeef-2893-4a04-9ebf-ecdc851475bc']}]
```

the query builder method looks like:

```
public List<Branch> find(String order, JSONArray filters, Integer limit, Integer pageNumber) {
    SelectQuery<Record6<String,Integer,String,String,String,String>> selectSentence = dsl.select(
            branch.ID.as("id"),
            branch.CODE.as("code"), 
            branch.NAME.as("name"), 
            enterprises.ID.as("enterprise.id"), 
            enterprises.NAME.as("enterprise.name"), 
            enterprises.NIT.as("enterprise.nit"))
            .from(branch)
            .leftOuterJoin(enterprises)
            .on(branch.ENTERPRISE.eq(enterprises.ID)).getQuery();
    if(order != null && order.startsWith("-")) {
            selectSentence.addOrderBy(Tables.BRANCH.field(order.substring(1)).desc());
    }else {
            selectSentence.addOrderBy(Tables.BRANCH.field(order).asc());
    }
    addQueryConditions(filters, selectSentence);
    selectSentence.addLimit(limit);
    selectSentence.addOffset((pageNumber - 1) * limit);
    return selectSentence.fetchInto(Branch.class);
}
```

And the `addQueryConditions` looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void addQueryConditions(JSONArray filters, SelectQuery<?> query) {
    for (int i = 0, size = filters.length(); i < size; i++){
        JSONObject filter = filters.getJSONObject(i);
        String filterCondition = filter.optString("condition");
        if(Comparator.EQUALS.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.EQUALS;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.GREATER.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.GREATER;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.IN.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.IN;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.LESS.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.LESS;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.LESS_OR_EQUAL.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.LESS_OR_EQUAL;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }else if(Comparator.LIKE.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
            Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) query.field(filter.optString("field"));
            Comparator comparator = Comparator.LIKE;
            query.addConditions(field.compare(comparator, filter.optString("value")));
        }
    }
}
```

but the field always come null...

how i can solve this.

Comment: There will be another bug with your `IN` predicate implementation, as you're not passing the JSON array to the predicate, but only the serialised array value, but that's not strictly related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The various [`TableLike.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-java.lang.String-) methods are case sensitive. Your JSON structure sends this input

```javascript
[{'field': 'ID', ...}]
```

Yet your column is renamed to lower-case `id`:

```java
branch.ID.as("id")
```

Comment: Hi @Lukas Eder, thanks for you quick answer, in a query `dsl.select(DSL.count()).from(branch)` how i can add a condition by the field name?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking me. Use the where clause...?

Answer (score 1):

I solve with this...

```
    public static void addQueryConditions(String filter, SelectQuery<?> query) {
    JSONArray filterArray = new JSONArray(filter);
    for (int i = 0, size = filterArray.length(); i < size; i++){
        JSONObject filterObject = filterArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String filterCondition = filterObject.optString("condition");
        Field<Object> field = DSL.field(filterObject.optString("field"));
        if(field != null) {
            String fieldValue = filterObject.optString("value");
            if(Comparator.EQUALS.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.eq(fieldValue));
            }else if(Comparator.GREATER.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.gt(fieldValue));
            }else if(Comparator.GREATER_OR_EQUAL.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.ge(fieldValue));
            }else if(Comparator.IN.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<>();
                if(!Constants.EMPTY_STRING.equals(fieldValue)) {
                    JSONArray valuesJson = new JSONArray(fieldValue);
                    for(int pos = 0; pos < valuesJson.length(); pos++){
                        listValues.add(valuesJson.optString(pos));
                    }
                }
                query.addConditions(field.in(listValues));
            }else if(Comparator.LESS.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.lt(fieldValue));
            }else if(Comparator.LESS_OR_EQUAL.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.le(fieldValue));
            }else if(Comparator.LIKE.toSQL().equals(filterCondition)) {
                query.addConditions(field.like(Constants.PERCENT_SYMBOL.concat(fieldValue).concat(Constants.PERCENT_SYMBOL)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the element filter is an array of ubjects..

```
[{"field":"person.name","condition":"like","value":"Carlos"}]
```

in the field i put the table and field `person.name`